# What is the use of くらい in this sentence?

Tags: words

**あなたは頑張りすぎるくらい頑張ったんですよね.**
I don't understand exactly the meaning of **くらい** in the sentence above. Could someone explain it to me and, maybe, give some examples too?

Comment: Would it help if you tried substituting ほど for くらい?

Answer (score 0):

Literally, the sentence means You worked to the extent that you worked too much. くらい is quantifying how much you worked. So it corresponds to the "extent".